# What is the benefit of using import X as X?

Tags: python, python-import

I know what `as` keyword does in import statement, we use it to give an object *a different* name in the module's namespace. It can be its simplified name(like `np` for numpy) or completely different name that avoids clashes with other names present in the module.

But, I've seen many libraries that give the exact same name to the object like:

```py
from package.module import FOO as FOO
```

Why? Is it different from: `from package.module import FOO` ?

couple of examples:

[FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/__init__.py#L7):

```py
from .applications import FastAPI as FastAPI
```

[SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L13):

```py
from .engine import AdaptedConnection as AdaptedConnection
```

and so many others.

Comment: @jasonharper Yes. I couldn't find it thanks.

Comment: So you can refer to it as just `FOO` instead of `package.module.FOO`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Without the `as FOO`, I'm still be able to do so. Have a look at the referenced link for the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I misunderstood the question.  Thanks!